# splitting label in multiple strings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, nsstring, compare

for my application I need to compare words but not the entire word. I want it to regocnize a letter if it's in the same place within the words. all words will have a maximum length of 6.

Both words display in a label.

label1 & label2

for example if the word in label1 is 'button' I want to split that in 6 strings.

```
string1: B
string2: u
string3: t
string4: t 
string5: o
string6: n
```

and then for my label2 is 'bricks' split it in 6 to.

```
string7: B
string8: r
string9: i
string10: c 
string11: k
 string12: s
```

now i can compare string 1:string7 etc.

this way I can compare all characters within the words right? My question is, is this the right way to do and if it is how would do code look like then?

I hope someone knows what I mean and knows how to do this! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
- (void)findEqualsIn:(NSString *)string1 and:(NSString *)string2 {
    for (int i = 0; i < [string1 length] && i < [string2 length]; i++) {
        if ([string1 characterAtIndex:i] == [string2 characterAtIndex:i]) {
            NSLog(@"%c is at index %i of both strings", [string1 characterAtIndex:i], i);
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know what you want to do with it or how you want to return the info (maybe an NSArray with all the indices that match in it?)

**EDIT**

```
- (void)findEqualsIn:(NSString *)string1 and:(NSString *)string2 {
    NSMutableArray *string1chars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *string2chars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //filling the string1chars array
    for (int i = 0; i < [string1 length]; i++) {
        [string1chars addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string1 characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    //filling the string2chars array
    for (int i = 0; i < [string2 length]; i++) {
        [string2chars addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string2 characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    //checking if they have some letters in common on the same spot
    for (int i = 0; i < [string1chars count] && i < [string2chars count]; i++) {
        if ([[string1chars objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[string2chars objectAtIndex:i]]) {
            //change the color of the character at index i to green
        } else {
            //change the color of the character at index i to the standard color
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the for loop compare `i` with both string lengths?  `((i < [string1 length]) && ((i < [string2 length]))`?

Comment: I got images in imageviews and when they (the letters) are on the right place I want that image to change to the same letter image with different color, (so another image)

Comment: But what I suggested isn't possible?

Comment: basicly the question is can I split a label with letter with length 6 in 6 different strings/layers

Comment: change my question or you change your answer

Comment: What I do now is I have 2 labels both in the background so you dont see them and when I submit one word to the field it compares the 2 labels if it's the same the word displays in green. What I want it do compare every indivial letter. So if 1 letter is on the same place I want it to turn green, Hope you understand

Comment: so you want to have different colors in the same label/input box?

Comment: No I have 2 images with the same lettr in them only other color so what is has to do it when I compare them equal = set the green one and when it doesn't it sets the normal one. :P it a little hard to explain

Comment: so you already have the code to change the letters to green/back to the normal color?

Comment: so you are looking for something like the second method of my answer? (if you dont use the arrays the first method does the exact same thing).

Comment: I will try this when I get home, is there a more private way I can provide you with more of my code? If it'doesn't work? thanks for this aswel!

Comment: Hmmm well we could mail.. if this doesn't work. Comment here and ill find a way to give you my email adress without everyone on the internet spamming me ^_^

Comment: Great thanks ! thanks for your effort. Ill comment in a couple of hours hehe

Comment: Hey can I still have some personal help hehe?

Comment: O nice dude je bent gewoon nederlands

Comment: Yea, but as there might be people reading this that have the same problem. xD

Comment: Oke let's disgust it on the other question I asked when I get it I will make an detailed final explanation in this post

Comment: You might find [chat] useful, although it does require 20 rep to participate.

Comment: I tried to move to chat, but user he doesn't have enough rep, or so the message says ^_^

Comment: Thanks Can I give my email? :P

Comment: then I can explain it in dutch because it seems that My explanations aren't realy understandable

Comment: sure, add it and ill mail you and then remove it from here (you dont want some ppl spamming you xD)

Comment: got it, you can remove it ^_^